# How do I start a new activity when a tab is clicked?

Tags: java, android, tabs, android-activity, android-actionbar

I have this class:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements TabListener{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Set up the action bar.
        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        ActionBar.Tab TestTab = actionBar.newTab().setText("The test");
        ActionBar.Tab chatTab = actionBar.newTab().setText("Chat");

        TestTab.setTabListener(this);
        chatTab.setTabListener(this);

        actionBar.addTab(TestTab);
        actionBar.addTab(chatTab);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater actionMenue = getMenuInflater();
        actionMenue.inflate(R.menu.main_activity_bar, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        if (id == R.id.mapIcon) {
            Intent displayTheMap = new Intent(this, Map.class);
            startActivity(displayTheMap);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

    public void showTheMap(View mainView){
        Intent displayTheMap = new Intent(this, Map.class);
        startActivity(displayTheMap);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

As you can see I have placed 2 tabs under the action bar. Now everything looks just fine, but, how do I execute a pair of code, when a tab is clicked? I mean, it is clear that I have to write my code here:

```
@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
```

But how do I know wich tab is selected? Can someone give me a clue, because as a beginner, it is seems hard to understand. I know that I'm missing a small part here.

Comment: you can see my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the below code

Please us the below code.

```
@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
    int position = tab.getPosition();
    switch(position){
    case 0:
       //code for test
       break;

    case 1:
      //code for chat
      break;
 }
}
```

Comment: Worked. I didn't expected to be so easy. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you can try this :

```
  public class MainActivity extends TabActivity {   
            static TabHost mytabs;

        mytabs = getTabHost();
            mytabs.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onTabChanged(String arg0) {         
                    Log.i("***Selected Tab", "Im currently in tab with index::" + mytabs.getCurrentTab());
                }       
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally I would solve this like in the official docs. [Here is a link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Tabs)

What is suggested there is to implement a separate `TabListener` like this:

```
public static class TabListener<T extends Fragment> implements ActionBar.TabListener {
    private Fragment mFragment;
    private final Activity mActivity;
    private final String mTag;
    private final Class<T> mClass;

    /** Constructor used each time a new tab is created.
     * @param activity  The host Activity, used to instantiate the fragment
     * @param tag  The identifier tag for the fragment
     * @param clz  The fragment's Class, used to instantiate the fragment
     */
    public TabListener(Activity activity, String tag, Class<T> clz) {
        mActivity = activity;
        mTag = tag;
        mClass = clz;
    }

    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // Check if the fragment is already initialized
        if (mFragment == null) {
            // If not, instantiate and add it to the activity
            mFragment = Fragment.instantiate(mActivity, mClass.getName());
            ft.add(android.R.id.content, mFragment, mTag);
        } else {
            // If it exists, simply attach it in order to show it
            ft.attach(mFragment);
        }
    }

    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        if (mFragment != null) {
            // Detach the fragment, because another one is being attached
            ft.detach(mFragment);
        }
    }

    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // User selected the already selected tab. Usually do nothing.
    }
}
```

And then add tabs like this:

```
Tab tab = actionBar.newTab()
        .setText(R.string.artist)
        .setTabListener(new TabListener<ArtistFragment>(this, "artist", ArtistFragment.class));
```

The class you give the listener in the constructor determines the class of the `Fragment` which will be opened if the tab is selected.

Comment: Answer seems irrelevant to the asked question.

Comment: @SunnyGarg How is it irrelevant? It is exactly what he asked for and not just that, it is the solution from the official docs. That's how you differentiate between which tab has been clicked.

Comment: @SunnyGarg I don't understand this random down voting that's always going on when there is a disagreement about a solution...

Comment: @SunnyGarg Your new solution is better. But I think it's still not optimal because it basically has the same problem as with the `Strings`. If the position of the tabs changes in the future you need to update the code. But this is not a place for discussions about best practices. The OP can decide which solutions he likes best. I just think it's ridiculous that I get down voted for posting the solution from the official docs...

Comment: Thanks for your response @Xaver Kapeller, I gave down vote becoz your answer is not as per the question asked. Any way that is my thought. I might be wrong.

Answer (score -2):

try this code

```
@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
 if(tab.getText().equals("The test"){
  //the test tab is selected
 }
else if(tab.getText().equals("Chat"){
  // the chat tab is selected
 }
}
```

Comment: This is not a good solution. Especially hardcoding the `Strings` like that is a bad idea.

Comment: you can use tab.getPosition()[start position is 0]. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.Tab.html#getPosition%28%29

Comment: or can use setTag/ getTag conception for differentiate between tabs, like @Sunny Garg answer.